# Wrong number of commits in Git? What do I do wrong?

Tags: git, github, branch, gitkraken

I started a little project few weeks ago and today I wanted to see the number of commits I did in a specific branch. I had three branches (master, develop and laravel-authentication). I started with some commits on the master, switched to the develop branch, made some changes and then I wanted to start the authentication with laravel. I made an own branch, and when I was finished I merged it back into the develop branch. Now if i take a look on the number of commits I did, it also shows the commits I did on develop and master.

If I look at the graph, i can clearly see that I did 7 commits on the 'laravel-authentication' branch. But however it also shows up the commits from master and develop. I put some screenshots from GitLab and GitKraken so you can see what I mean.

Maybe I just don't understand how Git works, but maybe you guys can help me!

A small overview of the whole tree
[image: Small Overview]

If I solo this branch ('laravel-authentication')
[image: If I solo this branch ('laravel-authentication')]

Also on GitLab, more than 7 commits
[image: Also on GitLab, more than 7 commits]

Comment: What were you expecting and what do you see?
All I can see here is your commits and that you merged the `laravel-authentication` branch into develop, so that then is added to the history on develop.

Comment: My goal was to see only the commits made in the branch 'laravel-authentication'. Why should I view the statistics of commits made in a branch, when commits from master and develop get counted too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Maybe I just don't understand how Git works, but maybe you guys can help me!

I think yes, and I hope yes.

Suppose branch `develop` has 10 commits in it. You branch off of `develop` and create a branch called `newbranch`. How many commits does `newbranch` have in it? The answer is 10 (not 0). Now suppose you add 7 commits to `newbranch`; it now has 17 commits. When you view the history of `newbranch`, you will see those 17 commits. Git doesn't care that 10 of them are also on some other branch. The view you see in the first image that nicely color codes those 7 commits on one of your branches, is just a convenience that it can do because those commits are only on your branch and nowhere else. But all of the other commits are also in your branch.

Regarding your comment:

> My goal was to see only the commits made in the branch 'laravel-authentication'.

First I think we should not use the word "made" there, because once you merge one branch into another, Git doesn't know or care what branch the commits were "made" on.

Regardless, it looks like the first image is providing that for you. Conceptually, what you want is to see all the commits on your branch that are not on some-other-branch-TBD. That number of commits could very well be different depending on which branch you compare to. For example, from a command line you could do something like this:

```
git log --pretty=oneline develop..laravel-authentication
```

That will isolate all commits on your branch that are not in `develop`.

And your other question in the comment:

> Why should I view the statistics of commits made in a branch, when commits from master and develop get counted too?

I'm not familiar with those statistics, but it looks like that is a breakdown by author of commits on a branch. So, on that branch, there are 17 commits, all by you, and then it shows the average and max number of commits you authored per day. It does not appear to isolate commits compared to any other branch; to do that it would need two branch names as inputs.